# How to access object object in typescript - Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

My result looks like the below when i console. When i try to access the data in my view, i am not it appears empty. Am i accessing my data in the right format please ? Any help ?

**Results**

```
0:
age: 55
name: "Client"
number: "34034000"
```

**file.ts**

```
export class MyPage{

     this.crudProvider.getPosts().then((data) => {            
          this.mydata = data;
          console.log(this.mydata)
        })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-list *ngFor=" let item of mydata" class="main-list" no-margin>
<h2>{{item.age}} </h2>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Can you please put the result of console.log(this.mydata) ?

Comment: @Koga, it is already in question..check the first line with heading Results

Comment: Are you sure is it the exact result? It seems not in the correct json format.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly wrap your `data` in `JSON.parse()` method and see what it gives you in the console. It's probably that or you're not accessing the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your data object to json.
Try this:

```
this.mydata = data.json();
```